# How to extract date from string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings in following format:

```
Friday January 3 2020 16:40:57
Thursday January 2 2020 19:26:19
Sunday January 5 2020 01:24:55
Tuesday December 31 2019 17:31:42
```

What is the best way to convert them into python date and time?

Comment: Say more. Are the strings just stand alone like that or part of a larger string?

Comment: _What is the best way to convert them into python date and time?_ What is the issue, exactly? There are already tons of answers to that question available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: I do not think this question adds to the body of knowledge on Python date conversion. There are literally hundreds of duplicates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

*Install:*

```
$ pip install dateparser
```

*Sample Code:*

```python
import dateparser

t1 = 'Friday January 3 2020 16:40:57'
t2 = 'Thursday January 2 2020 19:26:19'
t3 = 'Sunday January 5 2020 01:24:55'
t4 = 'Tuesday December 31 2019 17:31:42'

dt1 = dateparser.parse(t1)
dt2 = dateparser.parse(t2)
dt3 = dateparser.parse(t3)
dt4 = dateparser.parse(t4)

for dt in [dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4]:
    print(dt)
```

*Output:*

```
2020-01-03 16:40:57
2020-01-02 19:26:19
2020-01-05 01:24:55
2019-12-31 17:31:42
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "Friday January 3 2020 16:40:57"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(d, '%A %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S')

print(datetime_object)
```